# javascript/jquery content rotator goes crazy (starts to loop very fast after sometime)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am using a very simple content rotator.

Although it seems to be working ok, sometimes, after the browser window remains on that page for a while (10 minutes maybe), the animation starts to play at high speed (like every "frame" just for 1 milisecod).

here is my html:

```
<ul id="contentRotator">
<li class="cItem">
    <a href="#"><img src="" alt="" /></a>
    <h3><a href="#">Text</a></h3>
    <p><a href="#">Text</a></p>
</li>
<li class="cItem">
    ...
</li>
...
</ul>
```

and here is the script

```
function tCycle() {
    var duration = 4000;
    var speed = 500; //
    var arrDivs = $('#contentRotator .cItem');
    var arrLength = arrDivs.length;

    var iCurrent = 0;
    var iNext;

    arrDivs.not(arrDivs.eq(iCurrent)).hide();

    setInterval(function () {
        iNext = (iCurrent + 1) % arrLength;
        arrDivs.eq(iNext).fadeIn(speed);
        arrDivs.eq(iCurrent).fadeOut(speed);
        iCurrent = (iCurrent + 1) % arrLength;
    }, duration);
}
```

I tested the page in chrome 16, ie8, firefox 7, opera 11 and safari 5. It only seems to happen in chrome.

Any ideas on what is happening?

**Edit:** I found out that when it's gone crazy, if I scroll until the bottom of the page and then come back up (the rotator is at the top), it is (sometimes) fixed, the speed is normal.

Comment: Working version: http://jsfiddle.net/jphellemons/fRGqA/ will open it in chrome now. I use chrome 15.x

Comment: that version of chrome (16) is beta at least. :P  Have you tested it in the current stable release?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested http://jsfiddle.net/jphellemons/fRGqA/
and it works on my machine.
I have Google Chrome 15.0.874.92 beta-m

[image: works on my machine]

You might want to use a jQuery plugin like [**innerfade**](http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/), because the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` don't work so smooth.

or use:

```
arrDivs.eq(iCurrent).fadeOut(speed, function() {
    arrDivs.eq(iNext).fadeIn(speed);
});
```

**Edit:** works in Chrome 15.0.874.100 too!

Comment: thank you for the return function recommendation. i used it. +1 for this and for the "works on my machine" logo. is it common to use it or is it your idea?

Comment: borrowed it from codinghorror, please don't tell Atwood! but I really recommend the innerfade plugin!

Comment: I am working on a responsive layout. I had a look at innerfade but it also requires a fixed height value, just like the cycle plugin. that's why i went with my humble script.

Comment: Hi Turzifer, containerheight is default on auto `containerheight: Height of the containing element in any css-height-value (Default: 'auto')`