# jQuery - Image rotation gets faster when focused after the focus was on another Chrome Tab

Tags: jquery, html

My image rotation works fine when the focus is on that page(I am using Google Chrome). But when I open another tab and view some other page, and when I return back to my page(clicks on the tab that has my page loaded), the image rotation is somewhat speedy !

I use fadeIn() and fadeOut() to show and hide images. Also, the code for this is enclosed in another function which is initiated using setTimeout() on $(document).ready() and a setTimeout() is used in the end of the function too (the function that I mentioned previously).

How to solve this ?

**EDIT**

Code used:

```
    var initialFadeIn = 1000;
    var itemInterval = 5000;
    var fadeTime = 2500;
    var numberOfItems = 0;
    var currentItem = 0;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        numberOfItems = $('.banner-img').length;
        $('.banner-img').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);

        var imgTitle = $('.banner-img').eq(currentItem).attr('title');
        $('.banner-title').text(imgTitle);

        setTimeout(imgLoop, itemInterval);

    });

    function imgLoop()
    {
        $('.banner-img').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

        if(currentItem == numberOfItems -1){
            currentItem = 0;
        }else{
            currentItem++;
        }
        $('.banner-img').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

        imgTitle = $('.banner-img').eq(currentItem).attr('title');
        $('.banner-title').text(imgTitle);

        setTimeout(imgLoop, itemInterval);
    }
```

Comment: I had the [same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849904/javascript-jquery-content-rotator-goes-crazy-starts-to-loop-very-fast-after-som) and not only in chrome but in other browsers as well. It is like the script accumulates the unrotated frames and then tries to display them all together. Could not fin a solution and used the [cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) instead.

Comment: Thank you. That looks working. But can you tell me how to use captions for the currently displayed image ?

Comment: Found it: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/caption.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

As turzifer suggested, I used cycle plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

And to display captions above the image, I used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:       'fadeZoom',
    timeout:   2000,
    before:     function() {
        $('#caption').html(this.alt);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Like in this example: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/caption.html (view page source to see the code)